# ESDoc: Ignoring Specific File

Tags: javascript, documentation, esdoc

While trying to document a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) file, an error occurred. To solve this issue, the strategy will follow a different direction. We aim to ignore the cause of the issue since the code do what we want.

For this project, we are using the [ESDoc](https://esdoc.org/) for our [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) documentation generation. However, as said before, the [ESDoc](https://esdoc.org/) parser behaviour is not admitting one of our files. By addressing the [Features](https://esdoc.org/manual/feature.html) of [ESDoc](https://esdoc.org/) we found no trivial solution to ignore some `foo.js` file on a specific directory.

So our question is:

**Is there some way to tell [ESDoc](https://esdoc.org/) to ignore a specific *file* or *directory*?**

We research over the issue and found nothing. Please, do not misinterpret our request over a solution, we really did an overlook on the available features.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe:

```
{
  "source": ".",
  "includes": ["\\.js$"],
  "excludes": ["(node_modules|docs|test|foo.js)"],
  "destination": "./docs",
  "plugins": [{"name": "esdoc-standard-plugin"}]
}
```

for exclude node_modules, docs, test dirs ..... and foo.js file.

Or

```
{
  "source": ".",
  "includes": ["\\.js$"],
  "excludes": ["foo.js"],
  "destination": "./docs",
  "plugins": [{"name": "esdoc-standard-plugin"}]
}
```

Only for file foo.js

I've done in this way.

Comment: Can you please ident the hereby code and deeper explain your solution? Thank you.